# Is it OK to cast an _Atomic Type * to void * and back?

Tags: c, atomic, void-pointers

Some libraries require a callback function takes an `void *`(not `_Atomic void *`). Is it OK to cast an `_Atomic Type *` to `void *` and cast back to use it? Like the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int Call(int(*f)(void*), void *arg){
  return f(arg);
}
int Use(void *arg){
  return *(_Atomic int *)arg;
}
_Atomic int g_x;
int main(int argc, const char **argv){
  g_x = argc;
  int y = Call(Use, (void*)&g_x);
  printf("%d\n",y);
}
```

Comment: Yes, because there isn't any reading or writing to/from your variable while it "isn't atomic."  Technically, atomic types are sort of a misnomer, as there really is no such thing, only atomic operations.

Comment: not a duplicate of [Are all pointers guaranteed to round-trip through void \* correctly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42287803) - it doesn't mention qualifiers like `_Atomic` or `volatile`.

Comment: The potential problem is not with the casts *per se* but with the dereferencing of a pointer to an `_Atomic T` as a (non-atomic) plain `T`. The representations/sizes/alignments may different, even between simple `int` and `_Atomic int` types. (Edit: But I see that you do avoid that, in the code you've shown.)

Comment: Not *entirely* sure that it applies here (qualifiers on pointers are weird) but note 104 to §6.5.4 (5) in [this draft C11 Standard](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) says: *A cast does not yield an lvalue. Thus, a cast to a qualified type has the same effect as a cast to the unqualified version of the type.*

Comment: Also, you can't actually have something declared as `_Atomic void*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C 2018 6.3.2.3 1 says:

> A pointer to `void` may be converted to or from a pointer to any object type. A pointer to any object type may be converted to a pointer to `void` and back again; the result shall compare equal to the original pointer.

So there is no issue in merely converting the pointer to `void *` and back; the behavior is defined by the C standard. This specification of the conversions does not restrict them regarding atomic types in any way.

The properties regarding atomic types apply to accessing atomic objects. (In particular, C 2018 6.7.2.4 4 says “The properties associated with atomic types are meaningful only for expressions that are lvalues…”) As long as the `void *` is not used to access the object through some non-atomic type, it has no consequence on the use of the object.